# Can't we initialize automatic array variables?

Tags: c

I was referring to the book ["Theory and Problems of Programming with C"](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0070240353) by Gottfried (Schaum's Outline series, 2nd Edition, 1996).
On page number 243 section 9.1 in chapter 9 on Arrays, it says:

> Automatic arrays, unlike automatic variables, cannot be initialized. However, external and static array definitions can include the assignment of initial values if desired.

I did not understand the meaning of this highlighted statement. I tried to initialize array (with and without `auto` keyword) inside the function and do not see any issue with it.

```
void func1 (void)
{
    auto int array1[5] ={1,0,4,1,5};
    charVar1='M';
    printf("%d", *(array1+4));
}
```

Added the image of the page[image]

Comment: Automatic arrays? Is it a VLA?

Comment: `external and static may definitions can include`...is this correct?

Comment: I do not think author talks about VLA. One of the earlier editions I have is of 1991 and even in that this sentence is seen. He mostly talks of Automatic Array variables.

Comment: the `auto` is implicit, which is why it doesn't matter whether you write it yourself or not.  The statement *Automatic arrays cannot be initialized.* is incorrect. However, given that the rest of the quote is broken English, I suspect you have mis-copied

Comment: Sorry, I pasted the quote from image to text and hence the text copied was not complete. Updated the original post with an image

Comment: There was a time when you could not initialize automatic arrays. That was a long time ago, in another millennium. AFAICS, even the C89 standard allowed automatic arrays to be initialized (§6.5.7 Initialization); GCC supports that when the code shown is compiled with `-std=c89 -pedantic`. Certainly, C99 and C11 both allow it. So, your book describes an archaic version of C and should be treated with suitable caution. And you should plan to never use `auto` in your C code; there is no advantage to using it. (If you end up coding in C++11 or later, you will use `auto`, but that's very different!)

Comment: I see that the book is from 1996.  I don't entirely trust GCC to complain about initializing automatic arrays, but having spent far too long just now looking for the words in the 1990 standard that prohibit initializing an automatic array, I can't find them, as I observed previously.  I suppose that the book might still have relevance if you're stuck with a C89 compiler, but the only platform where that's a problem is Windows — MS Visual C or Visual Studio doesn't support C99 or C11 in general.

Answer (score 2):

To answer the first part

> *Automatic arrays, unlike automatic variables, cannot be initialized*

<sup>assuming the *"Automatic arrays"* are actually *"array data structure of automatic storage duration whose length is determined at run time"*</sup>

Yes, here what is referred to is called a [variable length array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array). It cannot be initialized as for the simple logic, the size is determined at runtime.

To quote the `C11` standard, chapter §6.7.9, *Initialization* (emphasis mine)

> The **type of the entity to be initialized** shall be an array of unknown size or a complete object type that is **not a variable length array type.**

Otherwise, for a local variable without any storage class specifier, defaults to `auto` and an *automatic array* of non-VLA type, **can be** initialized, for sure.

Comment: There's nothing in the copied section to indicate that it's talking about VLAs. The section is just plain wrong.

Comment: If I am not mistaken, C11 came after C99 and C99 was released in 1999. But one of the books of this author I have with me is of 1991 edition and I am not sure if VLA feature was available at that time. Or what about in original C? Is automatic array variable initialization was not allowed? Mostly author is wrong it looks.

Comment: @JonWheelock I don't have a copy of that book, but if it says that an array having a fixed size at compile time with auto storage cannot be initialized, then, yes, the statement is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Trivial demonstration that the statement is actually *wrong* (as opposed to e.g. array-initialization being a common but non-standard extension):

```
void doSomethingWithArray(size_t sz, int arr[static sz]);

int main(void) {
    doSomethingWithArray(5,
        (int[]){ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }
    );
}
```

An anonymous array is created with automatic storage duration within the scope of `main`. Since it is anonymous, there is no way for code within `main` to refer to it to set element values. The *only* way to put values into this particular automatic array is via initialization. This feature - being able to initialize automatic arrays - is therefore legal, standard, and necessary.

QED.

Comment: The book in question is from 1996, so an example using C99 does not really demonstrate an error on the book.  The book would have been talking about C90 at the latest.

Answer (score 2):

Given that this book is rather ancient, the concepts of VLAs and compound literals were not invented.

Automatic variables is the formal term for local variables. There's even the keyword `auto` for it, but it is one of the most superfluous keywords in the language, since all local variables are implicitly declared as `auto`. That is:

```
{
  auto int x = 1;
}
```

and

```
{
  int x = 1;
}
```

are 100% equivalent, the auto keywords adds nothing (so nobody uses the former style).

So by the term automatic arrays, the author perhaps simply refers to plain local arrays. As we can see from the example in the question, you can initialize such arrays just fine. The book is incorrect and/or uses the wrong terms.

The author of that book seems confused in general: "assignment of initial values" is the very C definition of initialization. The formal definition can be found in the C standard syntax at 6.7.8, where "assignment-expression" is one of the valid forms for initialization.

I'd recommend to find another book, preferably one that covers the latest C standards C99 and C11.